# Passing parameters in Razor checkbox

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor

I have custom three state checkbox:

```
<span class="bt-checkbox @filterValueClass" data-filter-for="@Model.GridName" style="margin-top:0px;"
                  data-fieldname="@Model.FieldName"
                  filter-operator="@Model.Operator">\&nbsp;\</span>
```

And I want to use standard two state checkbox:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Value.Value, new{@class = filterValueClass, @fieldname=Model.FieldName});
```

I have problem with pasing this two parameters beacause of dashes - :
data-filter-for
filter-operator

Can You help ?
I could change custom one to two states instead of three but it seems a lot of work to me.

Comment: You can replace the dashes with underscores and the framework will put them into the final html as dashes.

Answer (score 0):

For checkbox,f data is submitted,the data name will be the value of name attribute.And value attribute means if the checkbox is checked and the data is submitted,the data of value attribute will be passed to the backend.checked attribute can set if the checkbox is checked by default.So you only need to set the three attributes with `data-filter-for filter-operator ...`.

```
<input class = "filterValueClass" type="checkbox" value="{defaultValue}" name="{name}" />
```